# Dynamically predicting the time based on hourly average

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a table like this below

```
Date      Start Time  End Time    Hours  Capacity  Hourly Avg
2021-03-12  09:00      11:00        2      2         1
2021-03-13  09:00      12:00        3      6         2
2021-03-14  09:00      11:00        2      4         2
```

I have a set of orders with me, So based on the above table i need to propagate and find out at what time the below orders will be processed.

```
Q.No. Order no
1   "S0001"      
2   "S0009" 
3   "S00010" 
4   "S0023" 
5   "S0022" 
6   "S0021" 
7   "S00201" 
8   "SO7532" 
9   "SO7567" 
10  "SO7456" 
11  "SO7447" 
12  "SO7908"
```

For example, The expected output will be like below,Based on the hourly average on top i need to split and forecast a time when this will be processed.

```
 Q.No. Order no    Expected Processing time
    1   "S0001"        2021-03-12 10:00:00
    2   "S0009"        2021-03-12 11:00:00
    3   "S00010"       2021-03-13 10:00:00 
    4   "S0023"        2021-03-13 10:00:00  
    5   "S0022"        2021-03-13 11:00:00  
    6   "S0021"        2021-03-13 11:00:00  
    7   "S00201"       2021-03-13 12:00:00  
    8   "SO7532"       2021-03-13 12:00:00  
    9   "SO7567"       2021-03-14 10:00:00   
    10  "SO7456"       2021-03-14 10:00:00    
    11  "SO7447"       2021-03-14 11:00:00    
    12  "SO7908"       2021-03-14 11:00:00
```

I'm doing it with PostgreSQL version 11, But didn't able to do this dynamically.Any help on this will , Will be grateful.

Below is a sample code i use to find the expected time of processing of the orders,But i have remaining x orders which cannot be processed today and need to be processed tomorrow and so on based on the capacity and the hourly average.

Basically i need the below code to be recursive and do it same for other days.
I'm stuck at doing it dynamically.Any solution for this ?

```
 With orders_to_be_processed_estimation AS
    (
    select *,NTILE(orders_picked_today/hourly_average) 
OVER(ORDER BY queue_no) as partitions
    from pending_orders_to_be_picked_details
    ORDER BY partitions,queue_no
    )
    SELECT *,NOW() + INTERVAL '1 hour' * partitions  
FROM  orders_to_be_processed_estimation
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=22e371776e16d8e6057e7b5a96ffe7f3)

```
SELECT 
    o.id,
    o.no,
    c.gs as processed
FROM (
    -- Second part
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)
    FROM orders
) o 
JOIN (
    -- First part
    SELECT
        gs,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY proc_date, start_time, end_time)
    FROM capacities,
        generate_series(proc_date + start_time + interval '1 hour', proc_date + end_time, interval '1 hour') gs,
        generate_series(1, hourly_avg)
) c
ON o.row_number = c.row_number
```

First part:

```
SELECT
    *,
    -- 3
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY proc_date, start_time, end_time)
FROM capacities,
    -- 1
    generate_series(proc_date + start_time + interval '1 hour', proc_date + end_time, interval '1 hour') gs,
    -- 2
    generate_series(1, hourly_avg)
```

Which returns (note the three last columns):

```
> proc_date  | start_time | end_time | hours | capacity | hourly_avg | gs                  | generate_series | row_number
> :--------- | :--------- | :------- | ----: | -------: | ---------: | :------------------ | --------------: | ---------:
> 2021-03-12 | 09:00:00   | 11:00:00 |     2 |        2 |          1 | 2021-03-12 10:00:00 |               1 |          1
> 2021-03-12 | 09:00:00   | 11:00:00 |     2 |        2 |          1 | 2021-03-12 11:00:00 |               1 |          2
> 2021-03-13 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |     3 |        6 |          2 | 2021-03-13 10:00:00 |               1 |          3
> 2021-03-13 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |     3 |        6 |          2 | 2021-03-13 10:00:00 |               2 |          4
> 2021-03-13 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |     3 |        6 |          2 | 2021-03-13 11:00:00 |               1 |          5
> 2021-03-13 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |     3 |        6 |          2 | 2021-03-13 11:00:00 |               2 |          6
> 2021-03-13 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |     3 |        6 |          2 | 2021-03-13 12:00:00 |               1 |          7
> 2021-03-13 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |     3 |        6 |          2 | 2021-03-13 12:00:00 |               2 |          8
> 2021-03-14 | 09:00:00   | 11:00:00 |     2 |        4 |          2 | 2021-03-14 10:00:00 |               1 |          9
> 2021-03-14 | 09:00:00   | 11:00:00 |     2 |        4 |          2 | 2021-03-14 10:00:00 |               2 |         10
> 2021-03-14 | 09:00:00   | 11:00:00 |     2 |        4 |          2 | 2021-03-14 11:00:00 |               1 |         11
> 2021-03-14 | 09:00:00   | 11:00:00 |     2 |        4 |          2 | 2021-03-14 11:00:00 |               2 |         12
```

1. Generate an hourly time series from start to end. Because we are only interested in hourly end times, we leave out the first hour, so start is an hour later
2. Generate a simple integer series from 1 to the hourly average capacity (= n). This duplicates the currently created time records n times. Now you have as much as records as you expect: One record per free capacity per hour.
3. Now we have to create a join condition to be able to join the orders table. This can be done using the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) which adds a cumulative row count to the generated series.

Second part is simple: I added the `row_number()` here as well to ensure the same row numbers as at the other table. However, if your id column looks that nice in your real case, it is not necessary, so you can join directly on it, of course.

**Unrelated**:

It is not a good idea to store generated/calculated data in the table. So, if you once changed, e.g., the `end_time`, you need to change also the column `hours` and the `hourly_avg` manually. These data can be easily calculated if necessary.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, Checking on it :)

Comment: Working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a running sum on the capacity to get "start" and "end" limits.  Then `join`:

```
select pop.*,
       (s.starttime +
        (ceiling( row_number() over (partition by s.date order by pop.seqnum) / s.hours) - 1) * interval '1 hour'
        )
       ) as estimated_start_time
from (select pop.*,
             row_number() over (order by queue_no) s seqnum
      from pending_orders_to_be_picked_details pop
     ) pop left join
     (select s.*,
             sum(capacity) over (order by starttime) - capacity as start_capacity

      from scheduling s
     ) s
     on pop.seqnum >= s.start_capacity and
        pop.seqnum < s.start_capacity + s.capacity
```

The calculation for the expected hour is a little tricky.  It divides the queued orders into groups for each hour.